# VueRouter is undefined in karma unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm getting warnings during tests running on my new Vue.js project. Wherever a component uses the router either in the template as a `<router-link>` or programatically as `this.$router.push('/');`

The tests are passing but logging these warnings:

```
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined"

found in

---> <RouterLink>
   <Root>'
```

I'm using Vue2 and the project is based on the webpack project generated by the cli tool.

My unit test index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, process.env.WEBSOCKET_ADDR, { format: 'json', reconnection: true });
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const testsContext = require.context('./specs', true, /\.spec$/);
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext);

const srcContext = require.context('../../src', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/);
srcContext.keys().forEach(srcContext);
```

My main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket';
import VueHead from 'vue-head';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
Vue.use(VueNativeSock, process.env.WEBSOCKET_ADDR, { format: 'json', reconnection: true });
Vue.use(VueHead);

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  head: {
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', href: '/static/favicon-32x32.png', sizes: '32x32', type: 'image/png' },
    ],
  },
});
```

Any idea what I'm missing to get these warnings to go away?

A basic test might look like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import ViewDTCs from '@/components/ViewDTCs';

describe('ViewDTCs.vue', () => {
  const Constructor = Vue.extend(ViewDTCs);
  const vm = new Constructor().$mount();
  ViewDTCs.$socket = new WebSocket(process.env.WEBSOCKET_ADDR);
  it('has a created hook', () => {
    expect(typeof ViewDTCs.created).to.equal('function');
  });
  it('should render page', () => {
    expect(vm.$el.textContent).to.contain('Retrieving DTCs');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your routes might not be set up anywhere in your test environment. If you're using Karma and [Avoriaz](https://eddyerburgh.gitbooks.io/avoriaz/content/) or [Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/), I've been able to test components that contain routes like this:

```
import { mount } from 'vue-test-utils'
import router from 'src/router' // path to your router
import MyComponent from 'src/components/MyComponent'

describe('MyComponent.vue', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
      router: router
    })
  })

  it('has a created hook', () => {
    expect(typeof wrapper.created).to.equal('function')
  })
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks - I think you're definitely onto something. I've added an example test for one of the Vue components. I'm using Karma - your example is leaving `wrapper` undefined though - I'm not sure the beforeEach is firing properly. Is there something I can do with my current constructor to jimmy the router in there?

Comment: @OKsure I recommend using `vue-test-utils` since it's the official unit test library for Vue. I added a more complete example to show how I'm using it in a couple hundred tests (I'm jimmying the router into the component in the `mount` function above).